# mysqld: unrecognized service

Tags: mysql, centos

I have a CentOS server which runs few web sites. Suddenly all the web sites stopped functioning and when I check that I noticed that MySQL Service is down. I am new for this server related things. I executed following commands on WebMin since I have access for that.

```
> /etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqld start
bash: /etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqld: No such file or directory
> service mysqld start
mysqld: unrecognized service
```

It's really strange since it worked today morning even. Can someone help me in fixing this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe it isn't called mysqld. Depending on distro it can also be called simply 'mysql' or similar names. Check your /etc/init.d dir

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like MySQL has been uninstalled

Check that:

> rpm -qa | grep mysql

returns something like

```
mysql-server-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6
mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6
```

Comment: These are the things I get for this command.

mysql-libs-5.1.52-1.el5.remi
php-5.3-pdo-mysql-zend-server-5.3.8-17
php-5.3-mysqli-zend-server-5.3.8-20
php-5.3-mysql-zend-server-5.3.8-18
mysqlclient15-5.0.92-1.ius.el5

Nobody uninstalled the MySQL that's why I am really confuse about this.

Answer (score 9):

I had to install mysql and mysql-server on my centos box:

```
yum install mysql mysql-server
```

Comment: This is worked for me, before I have installed like `yum install mysql` only. That was the issue. Thank you @SSH This

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar issue where MySQL service had gone down after some updates. The solution for me was a permissions issue with mysqld. The limited permissions did not allow mysqld to be executable. Try something like:

```
$ chmod 755 mysqld
```

Answer (score 0):

I had just experienced a similar issue and solved it.

After a little soul searching was able to determine that I made a silly typo when installing the mysql package (typed mysql**156**-server instead of mysql**56**-server) and then missed the notice from Linux that no such package exists (I missed it because I was installing packages in bulk and Linux gave me a few hundred lines of success messages).

I suspect someone else may have done something similar, so just leaving this note here for posterity.